# Characters with accent issue in jquery dialog autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery-autocomplete, non-ascii-characters

I am trying to display the word `Colón` as a possible entry in an autocomplete JQuery dialog. Unfortunately, I get `ColÃ³n` instead. I tried to HTML escape it, but it displays `Col&oacute;n`.

How can I have this word displayed correctly?

**REM:** The array entry is defined as following:

```
v["CR"]="Colón";
```

**Update:**

1) The doctype is

```
<!doctype html>
```

and I have a

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

2) I am using JQuery 1.8.3

3) The list local, or to be correct, in a Javascript file which is loaded with:

```
<script src='./incl/curr.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have performed an extra test and included the word in a pure HTML `<h2>`. It is displayed correctly.

Comment: I'm not able to duplicate the issue, here's a fiddle showing it working: http://jsfiddle.net/npEHn/1/

Comment: We really need more information, such as 1) What's the doctype on the document? 2) What version of jquery/jquery ui are you using? 3) Is this autocomplete list local or are you getting it through ajax?

Comment: The fiddle works for me.

Comment: DOCTYPE should be in caps but that doesn't seem to be the cause of your problem.  Make sure that your script is saved as UTF-8, like the smartmeta's answer suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your text editor uses a different charset. Change it in the editor to UTF-8 then check your words again and ensure that your page is displayed in UTF-8.

Comment: I was sure I had saved my js file in UTF-8. I checked with Notepad++ and it was UTF-8 without BOM. I saved it again with pure UTF-8 and now the issue is gone...